# Updateview create new record on update

Tags: python, django

I have model with slugfield as primary key.

i have updateview when i hit update button it create new object.

eg:

**old record** : title = data 1

**update entry** : title = data 2

**output** :

1. data 2
2. data 1

models.py

```
class mymodel(model.Models):

    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, primary_key=True, auto_created=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(mymodel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class myupdateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mymodel
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```
class myupdateview(generic.UpdateView):

    template_name = 'update.html'
    model = mymodel
    context_object_name = 'mymodel_obj'
    form_class = myupdateform
```

urls.py

```
path('myupdate/<slug:slug>/edit/', myupdateview.as_view(), name='myupdate')
```

Comment: Why have you made the slug the primary key?

Comment: due to requirement of project

Comment: @c.grey so the problem is that when you save using update view, it's creating a new object?

Comment: yes while updating it create new @shekhar

Comment: so you can simply do an if condition in save method that if the slug is present then there no need to change the slug or if it is a new object then create slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the custom save() method  you are using in your models.py 
It also triggers when an update is occurs.
you can solve it by identifying if the object is new or not

solution :

```
self.pk is None:
```

returns True within a new Model object, unless the object has a UUIDField as its primary_key.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could use the model signals in order to set the slug.

For example the signal `post_save`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save